# Xpath.each not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, rexml

My code:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'xpath'

doc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
XPath.each(doc, "*/categoryName") { |element| puts element.text }
```

I am trying to take object xml where xml is a string of xml... and retrieve some text ie - I want this text

I thought the code above would work, but it is giving me the following error:

```
undefined method `each' for XPath:Module
```

Comment: Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) instead: `doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml); puts doc.xpath('*/categoryName').map(&:text)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what 'xpath' library you're loading, but you don't want or need it. Confusing the matter is that REXML's documentation assumes that you have 'polluted' your global object via `include REXML`. Since you are not doing that, you need to provide the full path to the module:

```
require 'rexml/document'
doc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
REXML::XPath.each( doc, "*/category"){ |el| puts el.text }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `require rexml/xpath` and try [`REXML::XPath.each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/XPath.html#method-c-each). It will work.

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/xpath'
doc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
REXML::XPath.each( doc, "*/category") { |element| puts element.text }
```

One example:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/xpath'

doc = REXML::Document.new("<p>some text <b>this is bold!</b> more text</p>")
REXML::XPath.each(doc, "*//b") { |element| puts element.text }
# >> this is bold!
```